# "Something Went Wrong" while opening the layout in design mode

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm very new android development. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin. I'm facing a issue when opening `activity_main.axml` in the designer. I'm able to debug the app in the emulator this error is only thrown in the design mode.

#### Error Log:

> Indirect rendering enabled Creating LibraryClassLoader in shadow copy
>   path
>   C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidDesignerJars4571381395840691254
>   Setting id 2 on newly created ClassLoader
>
> Trying to load class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>
> An exception occured while loading control
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   mono.android.SessionProjectCallback.instantiateClass(SessionProjectCallback.java:404)
>     at
>   mono.android.SessionProjectCallback.loadView(SessionProjectCallback.java:204)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:270)
>     at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:289)  at
>   mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:657)
>     at
>   mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>     at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with the design library.    at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:206)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:200)
>     ... 20 more
>
> Trying to load class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>
> An exception occured while loading control
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   mono.android.SessionProjectCallback.instantiateClass(SessionProjectCallback.java:404)
>     at
>   mono.android.SessionProjectCallback.loadView(SessionProjectCallback.java:204)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:270)
>     at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:289)  at
>   mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:657)
>     at
>   mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>     at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with the design library.    at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.(AppBarLayout.java:158)
>     ... 24 more
>
> Trying to load class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>
> Bridge [resources.resolve.theme] Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle'
>   in current theme Bridge [resources.resolve.theme] Failed to find style
>   'toolbarStyle' in current theme Bridge [resources.resolve.theme]
>   Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme Bridge
>   [resources.format] You must supply a layout_height attribute. Failed
>   to process message Load mono.android.DesignerException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:46)
>     at
>   mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:217)
>     at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:296)  at
>   mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:657)
>     at
>   mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>     at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

#### activity_main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of visual studio. As you can see nothing is rendered at all.]

Comment: Try clean, rebuild. Or delete the obj and bin folder in your project, restart your VS.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT I've done that and error is gone, but now I've another problem, the designer is not rendering anything. No errors! The widgets are select-able I can change the transformation from the designer and also edit their properties but nothing is rendered inside widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone like me, after spending hours searching and trying different things, my problem was that I didn't close an XML tag, but VS failed to tell me so instead I saw `Indirect rendering enabled` and `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: My problem is solved, after updating the visual studio now everything is fine. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Mohit it is not true that only updating VS will solve your problem.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I don't know how? and why? but it is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me I had the up-to-date version, i.e. I had navigated to "Check for updates" and got the following:

[image]
All I had to do was hit "Clean", "Rebuild", "Build" as follows
[image]
and I was good to go. 
Hope this could help someone who runs thru the same error and has the most recent version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error:

Indirect rendering enabled
Failed to process message Load

i checked by design and found that i have created a table layout with three rows and three columns. and in third row i have put only one text view.

I have solved this error by putting three different tables. First table contains three columns, second table contains two columns and third table contains two columns.